# Get and save the input of a EditText (Inside an AlertDialog)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In some part of my app's code I have a method that shows an AlertDialog to get a value(number) from the user. But when I try to save it in a variable (int) and return it I get this compile error:

[image]

The error says: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable *bet* inside an inner class defined in a different method"

So I try making bet a final variable, getting a new error: "The final local variable bet cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

My idea is to call that method, show the alert dialog, get the input value and return it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `bet` as a Global variable.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    int bet=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    private int betDialog() 
    {
        //some code...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but as the alert dialog doesn't block the rest of the  processing, when I call betDialog() and in the next line I get the value of 'bet' I get '0'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the variable globally and use it.

For more explanation, see here,

[Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299837/603744)

And as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5997998/603744) by [jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

> Any local variable, formal method parameter or exception handler
>   parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared
>   final. Any local variable, used but not declared in an inner class
>   must be definitely assigned (§16) before the body of the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" to my problem I found is the next:

I moved the code that needed the users input inside the 'onClick();'