# Android listview - listener must override superclass method

Tags: android, listview

here's the code, I have problem with:

```
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view,
                int position, long id) {

            if(listview.isItemChecked(position)){

            } 

            if(listview.getCheckedItemCount()>1){

            }

        }
    });
```

it keeps saying that listener must override superclass method and that I cant call non-final variable "listview" inside inner class. how am I supposed to call listview.isItemChecked(position) then? thanks

Comment: Check and see the project's compliance(right click project->Properties->Java compiler->Compiler compliance->make it 1.6). In java you can't use a variable in a anonymous inner class unless it's made `final`. You either make the `listview` variable final or you use the `parent` parameter which is actually your `ListView` for which you set the listener.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5997998/726863

Comment: I checked that, I have 1.7. and thanks, I've fixed problem with that listview.

Comment: still the same problem..

Comment: oh ... I'm so stupid, I didnt check project->properties->java compiler, but window->properties->java compiler... thanks, it works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you read up on the use of `final` in Java. Technically, you could fix this by adding the keyword `final` before `ListView listview = ...`, so `final ListView listview = ...`.

However, a better option is to just use the passed reference to ListView in your `OnItemClick`-method. The parameter `AdapterView<?> Parent` corresponds to your ListView, so you can use the following code:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view,
            int position, long id) {

        ListView lv = (ListView) parent;

        if(lv.isItemChecked(position)){
            // ...
        } 

        if(lv.getCheckedItemCount()>1){
            // ...
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I fixed that in the meantime :) but the superclass method problem remains.. thanks anyway

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part. In that case, make sure you're using java 1.6 or higher (see Luksprog's comment).