# Table get selected row index

Tags: android, checkbox, android-tablelayout

I am having some problem when trying to get the value of the first column when the checkbox of certain row is checked using Android. Here is my codes:

```
private ArrayList<String> exerciseIDList = new ArrayList<String>();

private void BuildTable() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM exercise";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int cols = mCur.getColumnCount();
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    for (int j = 0; j < cols + 1; j++) {
                        if (j == cols) {
                            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                            cb.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            cb.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                            row.addView(cb);
                            final View rowIndex = table_layout.getChildAt(j);
                            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    int rowID = table_layout.indexOfChild(rowIndex);
                                    exerciseIDList.add(Integer.toString(rowID));
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        }

                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        tv.setTextSize(10);
                        tv.setText(mCur.getString(j));

                        row.addView(tv);

                    }
                    table_layout.addView(row);
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

Basically I have 3 columns in my database, ID, exerciseType and amount. When I do a for loop, I +1 the cols to add checkbox to the end of each row. And when the checkbox is checked, I supposed to get the value of the first column which is ID and store into the list.

However, from the codes I provided above, it does not get the value of the first column of checked row. It is just simply looping start from 0.

Any guides?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are referring to a non-final variable inside an anonymous class (View.OnClickListener()). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997953/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-i-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differ) for more information. I would suggest the following:

```
final int k = mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("id")); //I'm not sure what you named your ID column, but put that here
cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
           exerciseIDList.add(Integer.toString(k));
     }
});
```

Basically, just create a new final variable k and assign it to your return from the Cursor.getInt(). That should get you through this error.

Comment: But it does not get the value of the first column of those rows where checkbox is checked

Comment: Any ideas? Because I not sure how to do this.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are needed. Edited my answer. I think that will get you there. I'm not in a place to try it out, but you may need to change how you iterate over everything to get your desired result.

Comment: The getColumnIndex should refer to the ID column of my database? Because currently by using your edited answer, the loop still starts from 0 no matter what I choose.

Comment: Any ideas? Because it still does not get the value of the first column of checked row